# Make copies of a single directory to multiple directories with different names

Tags: bash, command-line, shell-script, osx, command

I'm trying to replicate a single directory (with sub-directories) to a bunch of new directories based on a list. For example I can:

`mkdir Fred Barney Thelma Louise Foo Bar`

How would I copy a premade directory (with some empty sub-directories) to the same set of names? For example:

`cp -r master_folder/ Fred Barney Thelma Louise Foo Bar`

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop to iterate over the directories you want it copied to and copy the contents of your master directory to each one:

```
dest=(Fred Barney Thelma Louise Foo Bar)
for d in "${dest[@]}"; do
    cp -r master "$d"
done
```

Comment: Thank you htor. I seem to get errors when I use the above. If I remove the wildcard after master/ it works but only makes the first folder 'Fred' Tried to vote it up, but need a rep of 15...

Comment: @user30191 Fixed that problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your directory names don't contain any special characters (whitespace or `\"'`):

```
echo Fred Barney Thelma Louise Foo Bar | xargs -n1 cp -r master_folder
```

This can also by written:

```
xargs -n1 cp -r master_folder  < <(echo Fred Barney Thelma Louise Foo Bar)
```

or more explicitely, through a bash loop (this works for arbitrary file names):

```
for user in Fred Barney Thelma Louise Foo Bar ;do
    cp -r master_folder "$user"
  done
```

Comment: Thank you F.Hauri! That works well. Great site here. Wish I knew a little something something to help in return... Tried to vote it up, but I need a rep of 15...

Comment: U could `accept` this response as you're the asker